# How can I declare a number in java that is more than 64-bits?

Tags: java, declaration

In a project that is related to security, 
it is required to deal with very huge prime numbers such as:

3136666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666313

I am using java, and as it is know that maximum number that could be declared is 64-bits (type long)
So is there any approach to deal with these numbers?

Comment: Use a BigInteger instance and pass a String representing the number into its constructor.

Comment: And you could have Googled this as it has been asked on this site many times previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) from `java.math` package:

```
BigDecimal longerThanLong = new BigDecimal("9223372036854775808");
```